# How to disable mysqld in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, startup, mysql, init.d

I have a few (Linode) Ubuntu 10.04 (64bit) VPSes, and mysqld keeps starting on every reboot on all of them --

```
$ uptime
 16:32:26 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.09, 0.08, 0.07

$ ps -ef | grep -i mysqld | grep -v grep
mysql     2364     1  0 16:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld

$ sudo sysv-rc-conf --list mysql
mysql        2:off      3:off   4:off   5:off

$ sudo chkconfig -l mysql
mysql        0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off

$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

$ !ps
ps -ef | grep -i mysqld | grep -v grep
```

How else can I turn it off?

P.S. I raised this question to Linode but they are unable to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need mysql, why not remove it altogether?

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add an upstart script that turns it off after it starts...or edit the upstart script for mysql to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL daemon is started automatically by [UpStart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) service.

The configuration file is located at /etc/init/mysql.conf .

If you want to disable it at next reboot :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo manual >> /etc/init/mysql.override'
```

If you want start manually the MySQL daemon :

```
sudo service start mysql
```

If you want to restore automatic start of the daemon at next reboot :

```
sudo rm /etc/init/mysql.override
```